# Problem with compiling document with XeLatex involve fontspec package

Tags: xetex, pdftex, compiling, sharelatex

I'm using the online editor ShareLatex and trying to compile my document that involves some Arabic text. The only compiler produces an output of the document is `XeLatex` but when I compile I have this error and consequently the compilation become slower and some other problems started to appear like the images doesn't appear.

```
 /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty, line 28
```

and this is the packages

```
    \usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{arabxetex} 
\usepackage{bidi}
\newfontfamily\Kayhan[Script=Arabic]{XB Kayhan}
\newenvironment{Farsi}
{\begin{RTL}}
{\end{RTL}}
```

any suggestions to solve the problem?

Comment: That's not an error. Show the real error message from the log.

Comment: AFAIK, you don't need the `Farsi` environment at all. Use the functionalities of the `arabxetex` package.

Comment: @Joseph If I delete it I start having the next two lines highlighted with red

Comment: @F505, since you didn't provide a MWE, we can only guess what is causing those two lines.

Comment: @Joseph sorry brother but what do you mean by MWE

Comment: MWE = a minimal (but complete) small example that people can use to debug the problem, but also you should show the error message that you got.

Comment: line 28 of fontspec is the test for luatex, so either you have an error message about luatex or you have mismatched package versions and you have a latex3 syntax error, impossible  to tell without an example to run or the error message that you got.